# C++ - Adding numbers to a list? (like Python)

Tags: c++, list, for-loop, append

I'm very new to programming, but am trying to learn both Python and C++ (One is work-related, other one is more of a spare-time thing). I use the following code in C++ to take measurements with a parking sensor:

```
> for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
>     digitalWrite(TRIG1, LOW);
>     delay(2);
>     digitalWrite(TRIG1, HIGH);
>     delay(10);
>     digitalWrite(TRIG1, LOW);
>     d = pulseIn(ECHO1, HIGH);
>     d = d/58;
>     delay(13);
>     }
```

This should measure the distance and store it in `d`. It will do this 20 times in a timespan of 500ms. I now want to store each of these 20 measurements and obtain the median value from it.

In Python, I can create a list, and then append numbers to it. Is there any such equivalent in C++? If not, what other method would be recommended to take a median value, without writing terribly long code?

Comment: If your implementation allows it: use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Why do you need any complicate structure but a simple array when you know in advance how many elements you are going to store? That said, please read a tutorial on C++, the different container classes are explained there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to go with plain C(++) use an array of integer values:

```
int d[20];

for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
  d[i] = measureValue();
```

If the STL (Standard Template Library) is available, use a std::vector:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> d;

for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
  d.push_back(measureValue());
```

If you are writing for an arduino, you may want to install Standard C++ for Arduino (see https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Thanks, it's not for Arduino but it's a highly similar product (Particle). I'll have a look which of these suggestions are available in my case.

Comment: since its fixed size consider using `std::array<int,20>`

Comment: Ah yes. I own the one from the Kickstarter campain (different name). Try the <vector> version, maybe they already added the STL. As Thomas wrote: std::array<int, 20> is a fixed length container with no more overhead than int d[20] but it offers iterators and a .size() member.